# DotNetOpenAuth, AuthenticationStatus.Failed - Message signature was incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

My asp.net site (not MVC, not WebForms) has a form that looks like:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://example.com/register/">
```

The site is using `REWRITE-URL`.

#### C# code parts:

```
private OpenIdRelyingParty openIdProvider = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

or

private OpenIdRelyingParty openIdProvider = new OpenIdRelyingParty(null); // tried both

//request part

Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/register/");                          
IAuthenticationRequest request = openIdProvider.CreateRequest(userOpenId, Realm.AutoDetect, uri);

request.AddExtension(new ClaimsRequest
 {
                                                                 Email = DemandLevel.Require,
                                                                 Gender = DemandLevel.Request,
                                                                 BirthDate = DemandLevel.Request,
                                                                 FullName = DemandLevel.Request,
                                                                 Nickname = DemandLevel.Request
                                                             });

request.RedirectToProvider();

// response part

HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

var headers = new WebHeaderCollection();

foreach (string header in httpContext.Request.Headers)
                {
                    headers.Add(header, httpContext.Request.Headers[header]);
                    Response.Write(header + " = " + httpContext.Request.Headers[header] + " == HEADER<br>");
                }

string requestUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", "http://example.com/register/", httpContext.Request.Url.Query);

HttpRequestBase requestInfo = HttpRequestInfo.Create(httpContext.Request.HttpMethod, new Uri(requestUrl), headers, httpContext.Request.InputStream);

response = openIdProvider.GetResponse(requestInfo);
```

---

result:
response.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Failed

error message:
Message signature was incorrect.

---

log:

```
2012-12-06 10:51:56,240 (GMT+4) [1] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth - DotNetOpenAuth, Version=4.1.3.12303, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246 (official)
2012-12-06 10:51:56,412 (GMT+4) [1] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth - Error while trying to initialize reporting.
System.ApplicationException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.nGetRootDir(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.InitGlobalsNonRoamingUser(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetRootDir(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetGlobalFileIOPerm(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Init(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.GetIsolatedStorage()
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.Initialize()
2012-12-06 11:05:43,568 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth - DotNetOpenAuth, Version=4.1.3.12303, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246 (official)
2012-12-06 11:05:43,693 (GMT+4) [7] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth - Error while trying to initialize reporting.
System.ApplicationException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.nGetRootDir(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.InitGlobalsNonRoamingUser(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetRootDir(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetGlobalFileIOPerm(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Init(IsolatedStorageScope scope)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.GetIsolatedStorage()
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.Initialize()
2012-12-06 11:05:43,802 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId - .NET Uri class path compression overridden.
2012-12-06 11:05:43,880 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP GET http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
2012-12-06 11:05:43,896 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - X-XRDS-Location found in HTTP header.  Preparing to pull XRDS from http://openid.example.ru/mail/1dorog/xrds
2012-12-06 11:05:43,912 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP GET http://openid.example.ru/mail/1dorog/xrds
2012-12-06 11:05:44,005 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Total services discovered in XRDS: 1
2012-12-06 11:05:44,005 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - [{
    ClaimedIdentifier: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    ProviderEndpoint: http://openid.example.ru/login
    OpenID version: 2.0
    Service Type URIs:
        http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon
        http://openid.net/signon/1.1
        http://openid.net/signon/1.0
        http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
        http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup
},]
2012-12-06 11:05:44,021 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Skipping HTML discovery because XRDS contained service endpoints.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,052 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Performing discovery on user-supplied identifier: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
2012-12-06 11:05:44,068 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis - Filtering and sorting of endpoints did not affect the list.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,068 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId - Creating authentication request for user supplied Identifier: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
2012-12-06 11:05:44,271 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId - Diffie-Hellman supporting assemblies found and loaded.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,490 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest (2.0) message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,490 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElementRelyingParty did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,490 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,490 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,490 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,490 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,505 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,505 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,505 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,583 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest (2.0) message for http://openid.example.ru/login: 
    openid.dh_modulus: ANz5OguIOXLsDhmYmsWizjEOHTdxfo2Vcbt2I3MYZuYe91ouJ4mLBX+YkcLiemOcPym2CBRYHNOyyjmG0mg3BVd9RcLn5S3IHHoXGHblzqdLFEi/368Ygo79JRnxTkXjgmY0rxlJ5bU1zIKaSDuKdiI+XUkKJX8Fvf8W8vsixYOr
    openid.dh_gen: Ag==
    openid.dh_consumer_public: AV6/OIetgoN8ACoHLA7T2IosRPpXxoRaijaqaBSpSeo3PhpU6HdHM18IS2lD+msnZ4KmeDeJ0lyvhXqOQ/j3ReNNMEh+3xiUVhnScDldFl6hNpdb+BkdqmHjCAuCAvn6rTltIKwnCLwTCzjG7QXejUBcop18eFk7o/+TkN0t/bM=
    openid.assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
    openid.session_type: DH-SHA256
    openid.mode: associate
    openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2012-12-06 11:05:44,583 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest request.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,630 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP POST http://openid.example.ru/login
2012-12-06 11:05:44,646 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Received AssociateDiffieHellmanRelyingPartyResponse response.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,662 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming AssociateDiffieHellmanRelyingPartyResponse (2.0) message:
    dh_server_public: UkkgTDl1Tf74YoLzwv1J6eWlJJa4aGhPnFhW7cvTwKSfqE2C4MZwMwqG/K3VZl1ErDZYS6Rl3ZWXG6jx40ajlJ8W6FtKHz6AxrpzbkDf9rwh1tiUJYKTMHL9QYrmt/9v6TWJu//hhyv+BV2SW9ZIOj4tuIU/WyFFIxUEVVsG900=
    enc_mac_key: 15YHh+muOtqdDgqKtQcwHyUyoYkGQfHdaXPJZccg6gI=
    assoc_handle: 991b142fc46c9618026e5358f6c0a7b5
    assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
    session_type: DH-SHA256
    expires_in: 60
    ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2012-12-06 11:05:44,662 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,662 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,662 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,662 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,662 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,677 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,677 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,677 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElementRelyingParty did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,677 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - After binding element processing, the received AssociateDiffieHellmanRelyingPartyResponse (2.0) message is: 
    dh_server_public: UkkgTDl1Tf74YoLzwv1J6eWlJJa4aGhPnFhW7cvTwKSfqE2C4MZwMwqG/K3VZl1ErDZYS6Rl3ZWXG6jx40ajlJ8W6FtKHz6AxrpzbkDf9rwh1tiUJYKTMHL9QYrmt/9v6TWJu//hhyv+BV2SW9ZIOj4tuIU/WyFFIxUEVVsG900=
    enc_mac_key: 15YHh+muOtqdDgqKtQcwHyUyoYkGQfHdaXPJZccg6gI=
    assoc_handle: 991b142fc46c9618026e5358f6c0a7b5
    assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
    session_type: DH-SHA256
    expires_in: 60
    ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest (2.0) message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElementRelyingParty did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest (2.0) message for http://openid.example.ru/login: 
    openid.dh_modulus: ANz5OguIOXLsDhmYmsWizjEOHTdxfo2Vcbt2I3MYZuYe91ouJ4mLBX+YkcLiemOcPym2CBRYHNOyyjmG0mg3BVd9RcLn5S3IHHoXGHblzqdLFEi/368Ygo79JRnxTkXjgmY0rxlJ5bU1zIKaSDuKdiI+XUkKJX8Fvf8W8vsixYOr
    openid.dh_gen: Ag==
    openid.dh_consumer_public: dZ/yq5ZOFVE18zJ0zKrAZDcihDBc5j43g0a+aUWdiYbVGGrTB++D1gySdk00vfG/zf7O+N8MnReGAFA4P6W4ZizB2beZ5RtfV6gQvQhFQOROZuWKPWL81yHhYi+q7Ml3hLhDb8kLXL1Iig4T8qVB41i1J5UTUeJ2X0hdMFo9i2s=
    openid.assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
    openid.session_type: DH-SHA256
    openid.mode: associate
    openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending AssociateDiffieHellmanRequest request.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,943 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - HTTP POST http://openid.example.ru/login
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Received AssociateDiffieHellmanRelyingPartyResponse response.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming AssociateDiffieHellmanRelyingPartyResponse (2.0) message:
    dh_server_public: MBRXCLP62zX+N9aTKlhCoPUHjaEZ1OOQb9JuHkz7Uy/ZkbfAqDZEPVKjGTF/fMQX4BKlueKDhYcIAzmri97SxHOWQvm/f5elKMcOQ/5x3PyI36gJS0DKla/X5+vo66ybIjV29xfw+BnFSgCcDFQXvPzv4HX56EU1gkiaAsOkBgI=
    enc_mac_key: aD1Pl6J5MGiCSh3CxZPmw7dntiaw6Z5HDS7Y3RhilOY=
    assoc_handle: cdcbb91ff7f0259d3beb237fe7d65290
    assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
    session_type: DH-SHA256
    expires_in: 60
    ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElementRelyingParty did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:44,958 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - After binding element processing, the received AssociateDiffieHellmanRelyingPartyResponse (2.0) message is: 
    dh_server_public: MBRXCLP62zX+N9aTKlhCoPUHjaEZ1OOQb9JuHkz7Uy/ZkbfAqDZEPVKjGTF/fMQX4BKlueKDhYcIAzmri97SxHOWQvm/f5elKMcOQ/5x3PyI36gJS0DKla/X5+vo66ybIjV29xfw+BnFSgCcDFQXvPzv4HX56EU1gkiaAsOkBgI=
    enc_mac_key: aD1Pl6J5MGiCSh3CxZPmw7dntiaw6Z5HDS7Y3RhilOY=
    assoc_handle: cdcbb91ff7f0259d3beb237fe7d65290
    assoc_type: HMAC-SHA256
    session_type: DH-SHA256
    expires_in: 60
    ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

2012-12-06 11:05:45,005 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Preparing to send CheckIdRequest (2.0) message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ExtensionsBindingElementRelyingParty applied to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySecurityOptions did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToNonceBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.RelyingPartySigningBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Prepared outgoing CheckIdRequest (2.0) message for http://openid.example.ru/login: 
    openid.claimed_id: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    openid.identity: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    openid.assoc_handle: cdcbb91ff7f0259d3beb237fe7d65290
    openid.return_to: http://example.com/register/?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http%3A%2F%2F1dorog.id.mail.ru%2F
    openid.realm: http://example.com/
    openid.mode: checkid_setup
    openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
    openid.ns.sreg: http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1
    openid.sreg.required: email
    openid.sreg.optional: nickname,fullname,dob,gender

2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Sending message: CheckIdRequest
2012-12-06 11:05:45,037 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http - Redirecting to http://openid.example.ru/login?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2F1dorog.id.mail.ru%2F&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2F1dorog.id.mail.ru%2F&openid.assoc_handle=cdcbb91ff7f0259d3beb237fe7d65290&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fregister%2F%3Fdnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F1dorog.id.mail.ru%252F&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.sreg.required=email&openid.sreg.optional=nickname%2Cfullname%2Cdob%2Cgender
2012-12-06 11:05:45,740 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Scanning incoming request for messages: http://example.com/register/?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http://1dorog.id.example.ru/&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=http://openid.example.ru/login&openid.claimed_id=http://1dorog.id.example.ru/&openid.identity=http://1dorog.id.example.ru/&openid.return_to=http://example.com/register/?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http%3A%2F%2F1dorog.id.mail.ru%2F&openid.response_nonce=2012-12-06T07:05:46Zvf6eA5G4&openid.assoc_handle=cdcbb91ff7f0259d3beb237fe7d65290&openid.sreg.email=1dorog@mail.ru&openid.sreg.gender=M&openid.sreg.fullname=1%20Dorog&openid.sreg.nickname=1%20Dorog&openid.signed=ns,mode,op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,sreg.email,sreg.gender,sreg.fullname,sreg.nickname&openid.sig=ub2/HvGGl8xnmUKEfeRzLFn/0ZUh6emENsWA/eajF20=&page.id=6070266&keys.count=0
2012-12-06 11:05:45,740 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Incoming HTTP request: GET http://example.com/register/?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http://1dorog.id.example.ru/&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=http://openid.example.ru/login&openid.claimed_id=http://1dorog.id.example.ru/&openid.identity=http://1dorog.id.example.ru/&openid.return_to=http://example.com/register/?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http%3A%2F%2F1dorog.id.mail.ru%2F&openid.response_nonce=2012-12-06T07:05:46Zvf6eA5G4&openid.assoc_handle=cdcbb91ff7f0259d3beb237fe7d65290&openid.sreg.email=1dorog@mail.ru&openid.sreg.gender=M&openid.sreg.fullname=1%20Dorog&openid.sreg.nickname=1%20Dorog&openid.signed=ns,mode,op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,sreg.email,sreg.gender,sreg.fullname,sreg.nickname&openid.sig=ub2/HvGGl8xnmUKEfeRzLFn/0ZUh6emENsWA/eajF20=&page.id=6070266&keys.count=0
2012-12-06 11:05:45,771 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Incoming request received: PositiveAssertionResponse
2012-12-06 11:05:45,771 (GMT+4) [7] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel - Processing incoming PositiveAssertionResponse (2.0) message:
    openid.claimed_id: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    openid.identity: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    openid.sig: ub2/HvGGl8xnmUKEfeRzLFn/0ZUh6emENsWA/eajF20=
    openid.signed: ns,mode,op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,sreg.email,sreg.gender,sreg.fullname,sreg.nickname
    openid.assoc_handle: cdcbb91ff7f0259d3beb237fe7d65290
    openid.op_endpoint: http://openid.example.ru/login
    openid.return_to: http://example.com/register/?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    openid.response_nonce: 2012-12-06T07:05:46Zvf6eA5G4
    openid.mode: id_res
    openid.ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
    dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    openid.sreg.email: 1dorog@example.ru
    openid.sreg.gender: M
    openid.sreg.fullname: 1 Dorog
    openid.sreg.nickname: 1 Dorog
    example.id: 6070266
    keys.count: 0

2012-12-06 11:05:45,771 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.ReturnToSignatureBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,771 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.ChannelElements.BackwardCompatibilityBindingElement did not apply to message.
2012-12-06 11:05:45,771 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Verifying incoming PositiveAssertionResponse message signature of: ub2/HvGGl8xnmUKEfeRzLFn/0ZUh6emENsWA/eajF20=
2012-12-06 11:05:45,802 (GMT+4) [7] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.Signatures - Signing these message parts: 
    ns: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
    mode: id_res
    op_endpoint: http://openid.example.ru/login
    claimed_id: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    identity: http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    return_to: http://example.com/register/?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http://1dorog.id.example.ru/
    response_nonce: 2012-12-06T07:05:46Zvf6eA5G4
    assoc_handle: cdcbb91ff7f0259d3beb237fe7d65290
    sreg.email: 1dorog@example.ru
    sreg.gender: M
    sreg.fullname: 1 Dorog
    sreg.nickname: 1 Dorog

Base64 representation of signed data: 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
Signature: 9ELJCE2S2e6/hFNDpD16vfzcBuvW/+eo2X0imhmPLPY=
2012-12-06 11:05:45,802 (GMT+4) [7] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings - Signature verification failed.
```

---

If I not using URL rewrite - `http://example.com/register.aspx`, then all works properly.

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but this happens when your URL rewriter corrupts the URL such that it's no longer what the Provider sent. I see from your code snippet that you expect the rewriter to have changed the scheme and/or host and path, and you're "restoring" them to what the OP likely sent originally. That part looks fine. Since it's still failing, I suggest you *very* carefully inspect the query string that actually comes in (before the rewrite) and verify that the rewriter doesn't touch it *at all*. I suspect it's being changed slightly (perhaps changing the URI escaping of the parameters -- that's a common error).

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I'll explain how our rewrite url module works (it maybe helpful for you to understand my problem):

when we input url  - http://mysite.com/register/, our rewriter define page handler - for example http://mysite.com/register.aspx, and add to handler params - for example http://mysite.com/register.aspx?page.id=1&keys.count=0.

in request, I not pass them:
Uri uri = new Uri("http://mysite.com/register/");
IAuthenticationRequest request = openIdProvider.CreateRequest(userOpenId, Realm.AutoDetect, uri);

Comment: and in response, in query I got them - httpContext.Request.Url.Query contains "&page.id=6070266&keys.count=0"

Comment: also why returned param openid.return_to = http://mysite.com/register/?dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=http://1dorog.id.mail.ru/ , not only http://mysite.com/register/ ...